# Replacing all the Na values of a variable with 'Y' or 'N' depending on some other attribute's value in the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set where I need to replace all the na values in Credit_History data to '1.0' wherever the corresponding Loan_status shows 'Y' and '0.0' wherever it is 'N' in Python.
I have tried using If and else but that doesn't seem to work. 
Any help in this regard will be appreciated.
Code that I wrote is as follows:

```
if df['Credit_History'] == '' and df['Loan_Status'] =='Y':
    df['Credit_History'] == "1.0"
else:
    df['Credit_History'] =="0.0"
```

Comment: Can you please show the code you have tried? Asking someone to write the code for you is not a valid question on StackOverflow, but we'd be happy to help debug code you've tried.

Comment: Apologies forgot to share the code for this.Below is the code that I tried for this problem:
if df['Credit_History']== '' and df['Loan_Status']=='Y' :
 #   df['Credit_History']== "1.0"
#else:
 #    df['Credit_History']=="0.0"
**Ignore the '#' in the code

Comment: Thanks! Can you edit your question and put that in there? If you use four spaces in front of the code lines they will be highlighted and it means people can read the code easier.

Comment: Could someone help me with the above problem?

Comment: Thanks it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
credit_na_mask = df['Credit_History'] == ''
loan_status_mask = df['Loan_Status'] == 'Y'

df.loc[credit_na_mask & loan_status_mask, 'Credit_History'] = '1.0'
df.loc[credit_na_mask & ~loan_status_mask, 'Credit_History'] = '0.0'
```